# How to load a SWF and some extra data in the same request?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, arrays, amfphp

I'm loading a Flex 4.5 module (it's a SWF file) using a PHP code like this:

```
$module = 'modules/'.$_GET['module'].'.swf';

if(!file_exists($module)) {

    $module = 'error.swf';

}

$size = filesize($module);
$contents = file_get_contents($module);

header('Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.$size);

echo $contents;
```

and it works very well.

Now I want to get some extra data to load and populate the module with that data in just one request handler, something like:

```
private function requestHandler(response:???):void {

    var data:Array = response as Array;

    mySparkModuleLoader.load("", data[0] as ByteArray);
    myController.load(data[1]);

}
```

I was trying to do it with AMFPHP but the ByteArray seems to be broken or something because it doesn't show up, but the rest of the data is fine:

```
return array(
    'hello world!',
    new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Types_ByteArray(file_get_contents($module))
);
```

Maybe creating a multipart response like http://sun3.org/archives/107 and handling it?

Any idea will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG IS WORKING!

I hope that this will be useful to someone else so:

The AMFPHP 2.0 RC1 service:

```
<?php

class Services {

    public function getModule() {

        $path = dirname(__FILE__).'\..\..\Modules\Foo.swf';
        $ba = new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Types_ByteArray(file_get_contents($path));

        return array(
            $ba,
            array(
                'colors' => array(
                    'red',
                    'green',
                    'blue'
                ),
                'animals' => array(
                    'dog',
                    'cat'
                )
            )
        );

    }

}
```

The service (using Flex SDK 4.5) handler:

```
private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {

    var response:Array = event.result as Array;

    moduleLoader.loadModule("http://some.random.url", response[0] as ByteArray);
    initialData = response[1] as Array;

}
```

And that's it!

Comment: Hah, thanks for sharing. This is almost what I need. Trying to figure out how to manipulate the ByteArray directly. If I change anything I'm getting malformed packets. I'm guessing somewhere in the byte array is a length that's catching me... zzz.